# Auto-updatable values in angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, date

I have array of dates `$scope.dates = []` (`$scope.dates[0].date`). I need to create another array with auto-updateble(!) values of durations.

- `$scope.dates[i].duration = Date.now() - $scope.dates[i].date`.

I want to create timer in seconds:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in dates">
<td>{{x.date | date:'HH:mm:ss'}}</td>
<td>{{x.duration}}</td>
```

Edit: Probled solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call this function, it will maintain object in `$rootScope object`:

```
$rootScope.timerActivate = function () {

        console.log('activateTimer ::');
        if(!$rootScope.time)
        {
            $rootScope.time = {}
        }        
        var countDown = function () {

            var today = new Date();
            var hours = new Date().getHours();
            var hours = (hours + 24) % 24;
            var mid = 'am';
            if (hours == 0) { //At 00 hours we need to show 12 am
                hours = 12;
            }
            else if (hours > 12)
            {
                hours = hours % 12;
                mid = 'pm';
            }
            var minute = today.getMinutes();
            var sec = today.getSeconds();
            $rootScope.time.hours = (hours < 10) ? '0' + hours : hours;
            $rootScope.time.minutes = (minute < 10) ? '0' + minute : minute;
            $rootScope.time.seconds = (sec < 10) ? '0' + sec : sec;
            $rootScope.time.blink = (sec % 2) ? ':' : ' ';
            $rootScope.time.mid = mid;
            $timeout(countDown, 1000);
        };

        $timeout(countDown, 1000);

    };
```

Comment: Don't put this in `$rootScope` make a directive.

Comment: Why `new Date().getHours()` and not `today.getHours()`? What is the expected effect of `hours = (hours + 24) % 24`?

Comment: OK @RobG

,
Welcome NickNick

Answer (score -1):

You should use $interval. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval